# Automatically decline meeting invites in Mail or Outlook

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office, calendar

Many people are inviting me to meetings all the time and I'd rather they not assume that I'll be at the meeting if I don't have time to respond myself.

How can I automatically and indiscriminately decline every calendar invite I receive in my inbox? Right now I'm using Outlook for my mail but I'd be willing to switch to Mail if I could do it there and not in Outlook.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to indiscriminately decline every single calendar event invite that you get in your inbox?

Comment: Yes indeed. I'll make that more clear in the OP.

Comment: Hmm... I'll try to think of something, but as an aside, shouldn't non-responses to invites imply that you are not going to show? Seems rather strange that your colleagues are assuming otherwise.

Comment: Odd, you can automatically accept/decline calendar events in Outlook 2016 for the PC but I don't see that option on the Mac version nor is that option available for Outlook Web Access. I wonder if a rule could be set up in Outlook that does that...

Comment: I don't have Outlook for Mac but in Windows you can go to `Options -> Calendar -> Auto Accept/Decline` and set it to decline every conflicting or recurring invite.  You can't Decline every invite.  I'm thinking the Mac version would be similar.